# Hide row_number() column

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm using row_number() as a counter to see if there is any data with the conditions i specified. I want rows where p = 1 but I don't need the actual column that gives p=1 for every row. Is there any way I can exclude that column?

```
with base as(
select
      state.simple as State,
      customer_status,
      cast(created_at as date) as Order_Date,
      cast(dbt_valid_from as date) as Aktiv_Start_Date,
      **row_number() over (partition by lower(email) order by dbt_valid_from) as p**

from analytics.fct_orders_all

left join `analytics.dim_customers_history` on
    lower(customer.email) = lower(email)

where customer_status like "Aktiv%"
  and state.simple = "pending"
  and dbt_valid_from between created_at and timestamp_add(created_at, interval 14 day)
)
select *

from base
**where p = 1**

order by 4 desc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Big Query has a nice extension called [`SELECT * EXCEPT`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax):

```
with base as (...)
select * except(p) from base where p = 1 order by 4
```

Answer (score 2):

BigQuery allows this using `except`:

```
select b.* except (p)
from base b
where p = 1;
```

You can also use `replace` to change the names of columns as well.  These very handy modifiers are explained in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#select_modifiers).

Answer (score 1):

you can always avoid using `select *`

I have a similar query here:

```
;with base as(
select
     'Pending' as State,
      a.preferredName,
      cast(createDate as date) as Order_Date,
      cast(birthdate as date) as Aktiv_Start_Date,
       a.nationalitycode,
      row_number() over (partition by a.nationalitycode order by a.nationalitycode) as p

from [app].[applicant] a


)
select *
from base
where p = 1
order by 4 desc
```

[image]

Putting the list of columns `that I want to see` implicit in the select:

```
;with base as(
select
     'Pending' as State,
      a.preferredName,
      cast(createDate as date) as Order_Date,
      cast(birthdate as date) as Aktiv_Start_Date,
       a.nationalitycode,
      row_number() over (partition by a.nationalitycode order by a.nationalitycode) as p

from [app].[applicant] a


)
select 
 State,
 preferredName,
 Order_Date,
 Aktiv_Start_Date,
 nationalityCode
from base
where p = 1
order by 4 desc
```

[image]